# Naming Android mime types

Tags: android, sqlite

Naming Android mime-types/Uris:

The sample notepad application uses:
"vnd.android.cursor.dir/vnd.google.note"
"vnd.android.cursor.item/vnd.google.note"

Let's say I want create my own application with three datatypes that should be stored in the database, how should I name my uris?

Should all content uris start with vnd.android.cursor.dir and vnd.android.cursor.item before the slash?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It doesn't really matter. AFAIK there is no naming convention for it. Use whatever you like, just make them UNIQUE.

Answer (score 1):

**Mime Types:**

You should always make your MIME types start with `vnd.android.cursor.item` for a single record, or `vnd.android.cursor.dir/` for multiple items, followed by your custom vender specific name definition:

```
vnd.android.cursor.dir/vnd.custom.name
```

As recommended by the Android documentation found [here](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/ContentProvider.html#getType%28android.net.Uri%29)